# Prevent flickering when changing "Left" property in OnRenderSizeChanged

Tags: wpf, wpf-positioning

I have a main window where I want the "anchor" to be the right so that the window will expand to the left when the width changes. I did this by overriding the OnRenderSizeChanged event like so:

```
protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
{
    var vm = DataContext as MainViewModel;

    var widthDif = sizeInfo.NewSize.Width - sizeInfo.PreviousSize.Width;
    Left -= widthDif;
 }
```

The problem with this approach is that there is a flickering effect when this occurs as you see the window move to the left. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...Have you tried setting `UseLayoutRounding=True` ?